# subgrouping within a list in R

Tags: r

For example

```
list1 <- c('A','A1','A2','B','B1','B2','C','C1','C2')
```

Is it possible to make it into a vector with names being 'A','B','C' with values of 'A1','A2' etc?

example output

```
A
'A1','A2'

B
'B1','B2'

C
'C1','C2'
```

Comment: What the general rule? Is the list always exactly 8 elements long? Are values always in order? Do nested values always end with numbers? A top level names always one character long?

Comment: It's already a vector. Do you mean is it possible to make it into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
list1 <- c('A','A1','A2','B','B1','B2','C','C1','C2')
split(list1, substring(list1, 1, 1))
# $A
# [1] "A"  "A1" "A2"
# $B
# [1] "B"  "B1" "B2"
# $C
# [1] "C"  "C1" "C2"
lapply(split(list1, substring(list1, 1, 1)), `[`, -1)
# $A
# [1] "A1" "A2"
# $B
# [1] "B1" "B2"
# $C
# [1] "C1" "C2"
```

Comment: Yanzi, is this close to what you need?